# DVC(Data Version Control) keeps stuck at "dvc add xxx" with "Collecting stages from the workspace" in the terminal?

Tags: python, deployment, continuous-integration, dvc

I used : `dvc[webhdfs]==2.9.3`, installed by `pip install dvc[webhdfs]`

Then the repo is already cloned by git.

I have also typed : `dvc remote add -d storage webhdfs://xxx/dvc` and `git add .dvc/config`

But the command `dvc add ./assets/xxx/*` was still stuck...

The command line window keeps showing : `Collecting stages from the workspace`

Comment: Although DVC is a lot like Git, and uses Git for some things, the part you're using (and getting stuck at) is DVC-specific. (This step can take a long time, how long did you wait?) See aslo https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/add

Comment: Hey! How many file do you have in the `./assets/xxx/*` ? DVC by default should not be used to add tons of files individually (it's better to add the whole directory - `dvc add .//assets/xxx`). Also, is it a new project or old? And the last question - how many files/directories are in the workspace? If there a lot of them - could you try to add data directories to gitignore first please?